# Is it really a codec issue?

Tags: html, video, codec

I am trying to play the video but only hear the audio:

```
<div class='vcontainer' id='vc'> 
    <video id="match" width="700" controls>
          <source src='tsk1.mp4' type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
```

The codec for the video as shown is mpeg4 :

[image]

Why do not I see the video? Doesn't chrome support this codec? How could I play the video normally?

Comment: You should transcode the video stream to H.264 — the array of codecs supported across most browsers are unfortunately quite narrow: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: @Terry How do I transcode?

Comment: You can change codec of video using https://www.ffmpeg.org/  .net library.

Comment: @ketan Do I have to manually convert each video before attempting to play?

Comment: no once you found any specific command then you make one batch file or make one webservice which will automatically convert video from given video path.

Comment: You only have to transcode it once and upload it to your server.